# NoMethodError with collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-forms

I'm building a form for a `:has_many :through` relationship:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :employments
  has_many :people, :through => :employments
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :employments
end

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :employments
  has_many :accounts, :through => :employments
end

class Employment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
  belongs_to :person
end
```

The `Employment` model contains the fields `:account_id` and `:person_id`.

Within the account form, I'm adding:

```
<% fields_for 'account[employments_attributes][]', @account.employments do |e| %>
  <%= e.hidden_field :account_id, :value => @account.id %>
  <%= e.collection_select :person_id, Person.all, :id, :name %>
<% end %>
```

`collection_select`, or `select` as well, in any permutation I give them fail with a NoMethodError exception:

```
undefined method `person_id' for #<Array:0x82e7db0>
```

It's as if the `person_id` field doesn't exist and yet I can call the create method with `:account_id` and `:person_id` perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question. As I'm training my brain to think the Rails way, I've been running into situations like these where I'm simply thinking about the problem wrong.

`forms_for` needs to act on an already-instantiated object from the controller. Rather than this being a form to *create* the employment object, it's filling in the fields in an empty one. So, I needed to create an empty employment object in the `edit` action:

```
@account.employments.build
```

encapsulated with the proper logic so it only gets created when I need it.